# hardware accelerated h.265 encoding

Tags: pi-4, video

will (or does) the pi 4 have hardware accelerated h265 encoding ? I know it has h264 options like MMAL or OpenMAX (for ffmpeg), just wondering if anything is in the works, or if its possible(or useful in theory).

Answer (score 4):

Not encoding, just decoding (which is all they mention decoding [on the specs](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-4-model-b/specifications/))

As one of the RPi engineers / moderators mentioned in a post on the official RPi forums [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=243873#p1487281) when asked the same question:

> Not on the Pi4, it would require changing the SOC (or the SoC being
>
> redesigned to have an encoder).

He then clarifies:

> In fact H265 encode in HW is VERY difficult.

So seems safe to say that it won't be something they can retrospectively add through firmware updates.

Comment: He also says 'It can do it, just not in real time as that needs HW support.'. Does this mean that it can do HEVC encoding but will just take a long time?

Comment: This question is about HW support - the part "as that needs HW support" strongly implies that it doesn't have HW support :-) If you're purely interested in whether it's possible _at all_ then presumably yes it is possible extremely slowly in software but that's outside the focus of this question